# How can I set 3 or more Frames using tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I am trying this so I can place buttons in the medFrame, but they appear in the topFrame. When using topFrame, the button is against the top of the screen, which looks bad, so I figured this could be solved by using a third frame.

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.title('BulletHead')
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
root.resizable(width = NO, height=NO)  

topFrame=Frame(root)
topFrame.pack(side=TOP)

medFrame=Frame(root)
medFrame.pack()

botFrame = Frame(root)
botFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

botonJugar = Button(medFrame, text = 'Jugar')
botonJugar.bind("<Button-1>",jugar)
botonJugar.pack()

botonTabla = Button(medFrame, text = 'Tabla de puntajes')
botonTabla.bind("<Button-1>",tabla)
botonTabla.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Suggest that you don't use `pack` at all and instead use the `grid` method for geometry management. Find it far more intuitive. https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm

Comment: @AndrewAllaire: intuitiveness is very subjective. I personally find `pack` more intuitive, though I've been using it for quite a while. Arguably, `pack` is superior to `grid` if you're creating a vertical or horizontal arrangement.

Comment: How can I create space between the buttons using grid and using pack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the widgets appear at the top is because `topFrame` is empty. Since it has no height or width, and no children, it is only one pixel in size. If you give it a width and height or put some widgets in it, you'll see that the button is in fact in the middle frame.

Here is the image I get when I give the frames an artificial width and height, and force the frames to fill in the "x" direction (and also shrink the window down for illustrative purposes):

[image: screenshot]

Here is what I changed (note that I also added color to make the frames easier to see):

```
topFrame = Frame(root, bg="pink", height=100)
medFrame = Frame(root, bg="bisque")
botFrame = Frame(root, bg="yellow", height=100)

topFrame.pack(side=TOP, fill="x")
medFrame.pack(fill="x")
botFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill="x")
```

If you want the medium frame to take up all of the extra space, add the `expand` option and have it fill in both directions:

```
medFrame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

[image: screenshot using fill and expand]

Once you add widgets to the top and bottom frames, they will shrink in height to fit their contents, making it really easy top create tool bars and status bars.

Answer (score 2):

The elements have successfully been added to the middle frame however it appears as though they are in the top frame because the `topFrame` and `botFrame` have no dimensions so they don't appear (unless you can perceive one pixel). To get some spacing for the middle frame you want to supply some dimensions to the other frames. try this to give the middle frame some spacing:

```
topFrame=Frame(root, height=200, width=200)
botFrame = Frame(root, height=200, width=200)
```

An alternative to this is to check out some other options for using the [pack geometry manager](https://tkinterexamples.com/geometry/pack) with only one frame to get the desired results. Particularly the `expand=` option is helpful for centering objects in a window.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('BulletHead')
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
root.resizable(width = NO, height=NO)  

medFrame=Frame(root)
medFrame.pack(expand=True)

botonJugar = Button(medFrame, text = 'Jugar')
botonJugar.bind("<Button-1>",jugar)
botonJugar.pack()

botonTabla = Button(medFrame, text = 'Tabla de puntajes')
botonTabla.bind("<Button-1>",tabla)
botonTabla.pack()

root.mainloop()
```